# можно ли с помощью yandex-tank сделать нагрузку одновременно, использовав и uris и ammofile?

Tags: яндекс-танк

Yandex tank
Пробовал использовать метод multi, но yandex-tank выдает ошибку: 
"Both uris and ammo file specified. You must specify only one of them"

есть ли возможность обойти это?

Answer (score 0):

каждая конфигурация в секции `multi` наследует все настройки из родительской секции `phantom`. Если вы указали в "дочерней" секции `uris`, надо добавить `ammofile: ""`, а если указали `ammofile`, добавьте `uris: []`